# How to read time continuously?

Tags: java, loops, clock

I'm trying to make a simple alarm clock as my first java project. However, I cannot get my code to continously read the time. I am just using the simpleclock thing in java and I'm only going to worry about the hour and minute for now.

I want to find out how to update my "int hour" and "int minute." I'm thinking of reading the variables inside my infinite while loop.

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

```
Calendar now= Calendar.getInstance();
int hour = now.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
int minute=now.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

int k=1;
while (k==1) {

    System.out.println(hour);
    System.out.println(minute);


}
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to stack overflow.  It looks to me like you have two integer variables named `hour` and `minute`.  You set them to particular values outside the loop, then repeatedly print the variables.  But the variables' values are never updated in the loop!

Comment: Thanks! defining these variables inside my while loop did the trick. My alarm clock is working now. But for some reason, I've tried this before in Netbeans and it didn't let me define variables inside my while loop! I'm using eclipse now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a thread for this instead of constantly printing out the time. See the post above if that's what you (most likely) need; however, for purposes of learning what you did wrong, here's an explanation.

You are not updating your hour and minute variables as time goes on.

For example, if you ran this program at 2:52, *before* you enter the while loop, hours would initially be 2, and minutes would initially be 52. Then, once you enter the while loop, hours=2, and minutes=52, and will never change.

In other words, once you enter the *scope* of the while loop, as indicated by the `{` and `}`, you will not run the previous three statements above the while loop ever again.

Also, since the while loop will evaluate a condition, you can just replace your `k==1` trick with `true`, which is a condition which will always evaluate to true. Both ways are equivalent, but the latter is more *elegant*.

Here is a solution:

```
while (true) {

Calendar now= Calendar.getInstance();
int hour = now.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
int minute=now.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

System.out.println(hour);
System.out.println(minute);

}
```

Comment: Thank you so much!!! That did the trick. However, I did try this before in netbeans (I am using eclipse now) and for some strange reason it didn't let me define variables in my while loop.

Answer (score 1):

move the calls to new.get inside the loop.

Comment: I think you should be more specific and/or include your idea of the code. Your answer might be confusing to the OP, who seems to be new to Java.

Answer (score 1):

You should not while loop continuously to get the time. Instead, use `Thread.sleep(int millis)` to make your code wait for each minute. This puts less strain on the processor (your implementation keeps the processor busy with useless updates constantly). Also, to get the time, you should move calls to `now.get(...)` inside the loop. Try this:

```
Calendar now= Calendar.getInstance();
int hour = now.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
int minute=now.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
while (true) {
    hour = now.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
    minute=now.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
    System.out.println(hour);
    System.out.println(minute);
    // sleep for 5 secs (so minute updates will be accurate to 5 secs)
    // Thread.sleep is not always precise and inaccuracies
    // could build up if we slept for 1 minute
    try { Thread.sleep(5000); } catch(Exception e){}
    // later on when you build more complex programs,
    // you will make use of the catch block, but for now, ignore it
}
```

Comment: Thanks! defining these variables inside my while loop did the trick. My alarm clock is working now. But for some reason, I've tried this before in Netbeans and it didn't let me define variables inside my while loop! I'm using eclipse now.

Answer (score 1):

You'd need to move the now.get methods to the while loop.

If you don't want to keep doing unnecessary updates you could make a timer and only update once every couple of seconds:

```
import java.util.Timer; // import Timer

// Some Codes Here

Timer timer = new Timer();

timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // Whatever you want to do with the time, lets say print
        Calendar now= Calendar.getInstance();
        int hour = now.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
        int minute=now.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
        System.out.println(hour);
        System.out.println(minute);
    }
}, 4*1000, 4*1000);     // time to trigger in milliseconds and time to repeat
```